# Is is possible to enable Xcode autocompletion of Swift code snippets like 'iflet' in a top level context?

Tags: xcode, autocomplete, xcode14

Is is possible to enable Xcode autocompletion of basic Swift language code snippets like 'iflet' in a *top level context*? If yes, then how?

Use case: Just experimenting with simple basic Swift syntax in the main.swift file of a new Command Line Tool project. Just minimalist tinkering stuff that *is not required* to be inside of `struct`, `func`, etc.

*main.swift Xcode template*

```swift
import Foundation

print("Hello, World!")
```

In the top level context of a freshly created *main.swift*, `ifl` does not autocomplete to anything useful:

[image]

However, inside a `func` inside a `struct`, then `ifl` autocompletes to an 'If-Let Statement':

[image]

Another use case: Or, maybe just doing some simple math. A quick calculator.

Another use case: Or, maybe just demonstrating a basic "if statement" to a young not-yet-a-programmer without complicating the demo with other programming constructs.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to manually create a duplicate user entry and then change the availability scope.

Some observations of this workaround approach are:

1. be careful not to mask a completion that you do not want hidden.
2. does not have an explicit snippet import/export for backing up and/or sharing a snippet set.

   - The user snippets can be found in *~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/CodeSnippets*.
   - The auto generated UUID *filename* be changed to be a user readable filename.
   - The XML `.codesnippet` file can be moved to (add to) another Xcode installation.
3. it is tedious to make a duplicate user set by hand of the basic Swift constructs that work at the top code level.

[image]